# PHP cURL Proxy Inquiry

Tags: php, curl

```
$url = 'http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/ip.php';
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

How would I make this continuously connect to this server?
I'm working on a bot for this site to improve the technology. Also, how would I authenticate cookies on the server, for example: I send a  request to the server with this script using the certain cookies I would like to use.

Comment: Continuously? How about creating a loop and putting all code inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR where you can set the file that contains the cookie:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

Once you get the cookie you have to use the same $ch variable to keep the connection.

You can found a complete example of cURL usage here: http://blog.binacube.com/2014/08/complete-curl-example-login-proxy-and.html